# Replace values with values within brackets

Tags: r, gsub

I have extracted the first column of a dataset with twitch streamers names. Some streamers have their latin usernames in brackets.

```
"TheRealKnossi"
"TheGrefg"
"YoDa"
"Pestily"
"<U+D55C><U+B3D9><U+C219> (handongsuk)"
"GamesDoneQuick"
"<U+8001><U+76AE> (mobilmobil)"
```

I want to replace original values with values within brackets:

```
"TheRealKnossi"
"TheGrefg"
"YoDa"
"Pestily"
"handongsuk"
"GamesDoneQuick"
"mobilmobil"
```

I tried to use gsub()

```
gsub("(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", channels, perl=T)
```

The problem is that it applies to all vector elements:

```
""
""
""
""
"handongsuk"
""
"mobilmobil"
```

Comment: `gsub("^.*\\((.*)\\).*$", "\\1", channels)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))(*SKIP)(*F)` matches a substring between the innermost round brackets (parentheses) excluding the parentheses themselves, and skips the match, and then `.` matches any char (but line break chars, since you are using a PCRE regex in your code), and thus `gsub` removes those chars but the substrings in parentheses.

You can use a TRE regex `sub` solution like

```r
sub(".*\\(([^()]*)\\).*", "\\1", channels)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MYtdG/1/). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible.